# read the characters between special characters in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C language and I need a help on String functions.

I have a string variable called `mcname` upon which I would like to compare the characters between special characters.

For example:

```
*mcname="G2-99-77"
```

I expect the output to be `99` as this is between the `-` characters.

How can I do this in C please?

Comment: [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: Two questions:
1. How do you define a 'special character'?, and more importantly,
2. What have you done so far?

Answering question 2 is critical before someone answers questions for you.

Comment: There are no string variables in C. You probably are referring to `0`-terminated `char` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Travel the string (walking pointer) till u hit a special character.

Then start copying the characters into seperate array untill u hit the next special character (Place a null character when u encounter the special character second time)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `strtok` or `sscanf`

using `sscanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[64];
    int out;
    char mcname[] = "G2-99-77";
    sscanf(mcname, "%[^-]-%d", str, &out);
    printf("%d\n", out);
    return 0;
}
```

Using `strtok`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str;
    int out;
    char mcname[] = "G2-99-77";
    str = strtok(mcname, "-");
    str = strtok (NULL, "-");
    out = atoi(str);
    printf("%d\n", out);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` has great flexibility.  Used correctly, code may readily parse a string.
Be sure to test the `sscanf()` return value.

`%2[A-Z0-9]` means to scan up to 2 characters from the set `'A'` to `'Z'` and `'0'` to `'9'`.
Use `%2[^-]` if code goal is *any* 2 `char` other than `'-'`.

```
char *mcname = "G2-99-77";
char prefix[3];
char middle[3];
char suffix[3];
int cnt = sscanf(mcname, "%2[A-Z0-9]-%2[A-Z0-9]-%2[A-Z0-9]", prefix, middle, 
    suffix);
if (cnt != 3) {
  puts("Parse Error\n");
}
else {
  printf("Prefix:<%s> Middle:<%s> Suffix:<%s>\n", prefix, middle, suffix);
}
```